# require_once: No such file or directory 'HTTP/Client.php';

Tags: php, apache

I am working on ubuntu 12.04. I installed HTTP_Client by `sudo pear install HTTP_Client`. But when I am using `require_once 'HTTP/Client.php';`. It's showing:

`Warning: require_once(HTTP/Client.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mai.php on line 3`

How I remove this error?

Comment: Did pear report installing correctly?

Comment: Is there a file named `Client.php` in the directory HTTP?

Comment: Ya, Pear installed correctly. @helion3

Comment: Ya, file location is '/usr/share/php/HTTP/client.php'. @pekka

Comment: The warning should also mention the include path that was attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How paths are resolved when using `include` or `require` is controlled by the [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) php.ini setting, which is typically set to:

```
include_path=".:/usr/share/php"
```

*Whereby `/usr/share/php` points to where PEAR is installed.*

It can be set using [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) during runtime as well:

```
set_include_path(".:/usr/share/php");
```

*Should be run before you `include` anything else.*

Comment: Where i modify these lines? In my mai.php?

Comment: @user3171974 It depends; if possible, the most convenient option is to configure this in your php.ini ... otherwise, set the path in a central script that's included by all your other scripts.

Comment: Got it.
I just run this command on my terminal 'sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5', and error gone.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @user3171974 Since this answer helped you, you should have accepted it

Answer (score 0):

'HTTP/Client.php' is a relative path.  The error message means that the file doesn't exist at that location.  You'll need to modify the path, or move the file.

In this case your PHP file is in "/var/www/" and there is no HTTP directory there.

Edit: I would recommend modifying the path to be the full path rather than the relative path:

```
require_once 'HTTP/Client.php';
```

Change to:

```
require_once '/usr/share/php/HTTP/Client.php';
```

Comment: As you say i copied HTTP directory to my /var/www folder but now its showing different error 'Warning: require_once(PEAR.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/HTTP/Request.php on line 50'.

Comment: While on another machine its working correctly without copy HTTP directory to /var/www/.

Comment: The library you're using probably has further dependancies.  I'd recommend changing your `require_once 'HTTP/Client.php';` to match the full path to the `Client.php` file instead of attempting a relative path.  I'll update my answer to this effect.